# How to align rotated text in the table?

Tags: html, css, alignment, tablelayout

I found out how to rotate the text (thanks to SO) by 90°, the problem is the text is rendered vertically, but (I guess) the box is calculated horizontally (as **before** rotating).

I have table cell which contains such rotated text, and I would like to align the text at top of the cell. As the result I get something like this:

Text before rotation:

```
rotated90
```

Text after rotation (please excuse my ASCII screenshot):

```
0
9
d
e
t
a
t
o
r
```

Rotated text aligned to top of the cell:

```
0
9
d
e
-----------
t
a
t
o
r
```

So part of the text is above the cell actually, which is bad.

Desired effect:

```
-----------
0
9
d
e
t
a
t
o
r
```

**QUESTION**: how to align text vertically, i.e. how to make browser see the box as after (not before) rotattion?

Comment: IE's method (`writing-mode`) properly rotates the box model for the element, but it doesn't look like Webkit/Mozilla browsers do. :(

Comment: @jnpcl, thank you for reminding about it, but indeed it is too limiting, after all even I do not use Windows as primary system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible without specifying the height of the cell that the rotated text is in.

Webkit/Mozilla performs the rotation on the element's display, but not its box model.

The CSS3 property `writing-mode` works properly in IE, rotating the box model. This property should be supported by most browsers, but the article I read said it was only supported by IE at the time.

Comment: Since I am not in a hurry, I will leave my text horizontally, and after some time I will rotate using writing-mode then. Oh boy, WWW is everything, except keeping the standards :-).